# Method unmodifiablelist() cannot be applied to given type

Tags: java, method-reference, unmodifiable

I am trying to compile a former co-worker's code but it says that the method `unmodifiableList()` can not be applied to a given type. The code in Eclipse does not show any error. But it still does not let me compile it. What could be the error?

```
package framework.interview.demographics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xsdschema.Public;
import framework.data.people.NonReference;
import framework.data.people.people;

public class schedualData {

    private final List<people> schedual;

    private schedualData(List<people> schedual) {
            this.schedual = Objects.requireNonNull(schedual);
    }

    public static schedualData getSchedualData(List<people> schedual) {
        if(schedual.size() < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("schedual must   contain at least one people");

        if(Stream.of(schedual).filter(people -> (!(people instanceof NonReference))).count() != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There must be one and only one Reference between"   + "People, number, and Review");

        return new schedualData(schedual);
    }

        //****** Getters ******\\
       public people getReference() {
          return schedual.stream()
         .filter(people -> !(people instanceof NonReference))
         .toArray(people[]::new)[0];
    }   

    public List<NonReference> getNonReferenceschedual() {
        //This is where the error is showing. 
        return Collections
               .unmodifiableList(schedual.stream()
               .filter(NonReference.class::isInstance)
               .map(x -> (NonReference) x)
               .collect(Collectors.toCollection     (ArrayList<NonReference>::new)));
      }

    public List<people> getFullschedual() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(schedual);
    }  

   public int size() {
       return schedual.size();
   }
}
```

This is the error log/information that eclipse prints once I compile the application:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-      plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project 
         AutomationTesting: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Newbie/eclipse-   workspace/automationTesting/Data.java:[42,35] method unmodifiableList in    class java.util.
          Collections cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: java.util.List<? extends T>
[ERROR]   found: java.util.Collection<framework.data.people.NonReference>
[ERROR]   reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
[ERROR]     inferred: java.lang.Object&java.util.List<? extends   java.lang.Object>&java.util.Collection<framework.data.people.NonReference>
[ERROR]     upper bound(s):   java.util.Collection<framework.data.people.NonReference>,java.util.List<?  extends java.lang.Object>,java.lang.
              ObjectCompilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Newbie/eclipse-workspace/automationTesting/Data.java:  
[42,35] method unmodifiableList in class java.util.Collections 
        cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: java.util.List<? extends T>
[ERROR]   found:    java.util.Collection<framework.data.people.NonReference>
[ERROR]   reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
[ERROR]     inferred: java.lang.Object&java.util.List<? extends   java.lang.Object>&java.util.Collection<framework.data.people.NonReference>
[ERROR]     upper bound(s):  java.util.Collection<framework.data.people.NonReference>,java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Object>,java.lang.Object
```

Comment: `required: java.util.List<? extends T> ... found: java.util.Collection<framework.data.people.NonReference>`

Comment: The error message is quite clear. It requires a list, while you are passing a collection. Use `unmodifiableCollection` instead, or put the items into an `ArrayList`, for example, before calling `unmodifiableList`.

Comment: @Michael No, OP is passing an `ArrayList<NonReference>` but it's being incorrectly resolved because of `Collections.unmodifiableList` which generic type parameters have been resolved first. It distorts the return value of `collect(Collectors.toCollection())` to its upper bound which is `Collection<T>` or `Collection<NonReference>`. Please, have a look at my answer.

Comment: As a side note, `.toArray(people[]::new)[0]` is a very inefficient way of saying `.findFirst().get()`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare generic type parameters. For some reason*, it can't be inferred.

```
return Collections.<NonReference>unmodifiableList(schedual.stream()
                                        .filter(NonReference.class::isInstance)
                                        .map(NonReference.class::cast)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

or

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(schedual.stream()
                                        .filter(NonReference.class::isInstance)
                                        .map(NonReference.class::cast)
                                        .collect(Collectors.<NonReference, List<NonReference>>toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

or

```
ArrayList<NonReference> result = schedual.stream()
    .filter(NonReference.class::isInstance)
    .map(NonReference.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

return Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
```

Though, you could simply go with

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(schedual.stream()
                                        .filter(NonReference.class::isInstance)
                                        .map(NonReference.class::cast)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

*The problem is that `Collections.unmodifiableList` determines the type for `collect(Collectors.toCollection())`, and not vice versa, as you were probably expecting.

You may help the compiler with type inference by stating *exactly* what you want. You say either what `unmodifiableList` should take or what `.collect(Collectors.toCollection())` should return.

Any of the four snippets mentioned above will help you to resolve the issue.

---

`x -> (NonReference) x` can be replaced with `NonReference.class::cast`.

Comment: What `Collection`? He is passing a `Supplier<C>` where `C` is `ArrayList`

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with generic type inference. `Collections.unmodifiableList` expects a `List` and `collect(toCollection)` returns a `Collection`. You simply cannot pass a Collection to method that expects a `List`. Your example with `.collect(toList())` is correct but `.collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new))` is not.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Before posting, I have compiled these 4 snippets and they all worked.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel *"collect(toCollection) returns a Collection"* - it's not true. If it were, how would `List<String> r = Arrays.asList("a", "b").stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));` be possible? The return type is bounded by `Collection` (`C extends Collection<T>`), but it may be or may not be a `Collection`.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel and, yes, it's directly related to type inference and to the order in which generic type parameters is being resolved

Comment: `The return type is bounded by Collection (C extends Collection<T>).` Indeed, I misread the documentation. Thanks for taking the time to correct me and accept my appologies.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel No worries, I am glad we sorted it out:)

Comment: @Newbie I am glad it helped. I always employ this approach when something weird going on with generics.

Comment: The first variant does not compile with `javac`. But I think, it should. Well, actually, I think the OP’s original approach should compile too. By the way, just replacing `ArrayList<NonReference>::new` with `() -> new ArrayList<>()` in the OP’s original code also makes `javac` accept it.

Comment: @Holger Weird. I can compile all (java 1.8.0_201).

Comment: Using Eclipse or truly with `javac`? I used jdk1.8.0_162, however, since the question’s code is incomplete (it lacks the definitions of `NonReference` and `people`), we may have code differences…